# OpenAPI 3.0 - How to accept byte array or an object(a hashmap)?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I'm writing an OpenAPI definition for the oldResource field which can be an object (basically, a hashmap) or a byte array. Like below -

```
{"oldResource" : <object(hashmap) or byte array>}
```

How can I define such a field in OpenAPI?

I have tried the following

```
oldResource:
    description: Old Resource map/byte array
    type: object
    anyOf:
        - type: object
        - type: array
            items:
                type: byte
```

But, this gives me an error.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use type *string* and the format *byte*:

[String Formats](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#string)

```
  oldResource:
    description: Old Resource map/byte array
    type: object
    anyOf:
        - type: object
        - type: array
          items:
            type: string
            format: byte
```